# Windows Server 2008 R2 DFS Root Namespace Required?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

I would prefer to set up our DFS such as:
\domain.local\users
\domain.local\customers
\domain.local\support
etc.

Is this a problem? Do I need to instead set all of the above folders as targets under a root such as:
\domain.local\files\users
\domain.local\files\customers
\domain.local\files\support

Other than the path being shorter in the top example, which is what I would prefer, is there a difference in functionality in Windows DFS between the two examples shown?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple namespaces to get the shorter path. So instead of having a share and then your folders for DFS inside. Make each individual folder its own namespace and publish those. Though I feel having all the replicated shares in one place makes it easier for the users to visually pick the folder they want out of the many. They only then need to remember one path. The users can check our wiki if they forget it.

Our DFS namespace is 
\\DOMAIN.LOCAL\datastore and all the replicated shares are inside there.

There may be a slight performance increase in going everything in one namespace but I don't feel it is significant.

Hope that gives you a little insight.